# Как установить свойства для png перед сохранением Visio как HTML

Tags: c#, office, visio

Не могу понять, как можно установить свойство **`Transparency color`** (картинка ниже) для .png перед сохранением документа как `Html`.

```
var saveAsWeb = (IVisSaveAsWeb)_visio.SaveAsWebObject;
var webSettings = (IVisWebPageSettings)saveAsWeb.WebPageSettings;
webSettings.PriFormat = "PNG"; // тут я так понимаю, я установил формат изображения.
```

Но как установить свойство с картинки я не имею понятия.

Спасибо за помощь !

[image: Вот так]

Comment: А какая версия Visio? А то у меня в 2013 по File -> SaveAs (Web page) нет такого окна, только выбор между png, jpg и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде, перед сохранением `Visio` как `HTMl`, следует написать эти строки кода:

```
dynamic appVisSettings = _visio.Application.Settings;
appVisSettings.RasterExportUseTransparencyColor = true;
```

Где `RasterExportUseTransparencyColor` отвечает именно за `Transparency color`.